# Function timer prevents main from continuing

Tags: c++, loops, keystroke

I am new here. Little rusty after my C++ college class. I am trying to make a program where specific keystrokes log the text seen in cout. The problem I am having is that the **timer** function is preventing the **main** function from continuing. The **timer** function is made to increase **Tic** by 1 every time **Delay** reaches 28. **timer** loops and when it reaches 28, **Delay** resets back to 0. Why is it that my **main** is not continuing? Could it be that it is waiting for **timer** to finish looping? How can I make **timer** and **main** work simultaneously? This is not a homework assignment. Making a personal project.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int Tic = 0;
int Delay = 0;

bool KeyIsListed(int iKey)
{
switch (iKey)
{
    case 0x41:
        cout << "ACS_Execute(10,0,0,0,0);\n"; //the A Note
        cout << "Delay("<<Tic<<");\n"; //Capture the time
        Delay = 0;
        Tic = 0
        break;
    case 0x53:
        cout << "ACS_Execute(11,0,0,0,0);\n"; //the S Note
        cout << "Delay("<<Tic<<");\n"; //Capture the time
        Delay = 0;
        Tic = 0
        break;
    case 0x44:
        cout << "ACS_Execute(12,0,0,0,0);\n"; //the D Note
        cout << "Delay("<<Tic<<");\n"; //Capture the time
        Delay = 0;
        Tic = 0
        break;
    case 0x46:
        cout << "ACS_Execute(13,0,0,0,0);\n"; //the F Note
        cout << "Delay("<<Tic<<");\n"; //Capture the time
        Delay = 0;
        Tic = 0
        break;
    case 0x47:
        cout << "ACS_Execute(14,0,0,0,0);\n"; //the G Note
        cout << "Delay("<<Tic<<");\n"; //Capture the time
        Delay = 0;
        Tic = 0
        break;
    case 0x48:
        cout << "ACS_Execute(15,0,0,0,0);\n"; //the H Note
        cout << "Delay("<<Tic<<");\n"; //Capture the time
        Delay = 0;
        Tic = 0
        break;
    case 0x4A:
        cout << "ACS_Execute(16,0,0,0,0);\n"; //the J Note
        cout << "Delay("<<Tic<<");\n"; //Capture the time
        Delay = 0;
        Tic = 0
        break;
    case 0x4B:
        cout << "ACS_Execute(17,0,0,0,0);\n"; //the K Note
        cout << "Delay("<<Tic<<");\n"; //Capture the time
        Delay = 0;
        Tic = 0
        break;
    case 0x4C:
        cout << "ACS_Execute(18,0,0,0,0);\n"; //the L Note
        cout << "Delay("<<Tic<<");\n"; //Capture the time
        Delay = 0;
        Tic = 0
        break;
    }
}

int timer()//Doom Tic timer
{
    while(TRUE)
    {
        if(Delay == 28)//Aprox to 1 tic
        {
            Delay = 0;//Reset delay to 0
            Tic ++;//Increase Tic by 1
        }
        else
        {
            Delay ++;//Increase Delay until it is at 28
        }
        Sleep(0.1);
    }
}

int main()
{
char key;
timer();//Call timer Function (This is preventing the main function from continuing)
while(TRUE)
{
    for(key = 8; key <= 190; key ++)
    {
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(key) == 1)
        {
            if(KeyIsListed(key) == FALSE)
            {

            }
        }
    }

}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Please focus on the *MINIMAL* portion of [mcve]

Comment: Have you used your debugger or put in `cout` statements into your `timer` function so you can follow the logic? What have you observed if so?

Comment: It's worth noting you have declared `timer` to return an `int` yet it's currently returning nothing. This is undefined behaviour. You should make sure your warnings are at the highest level possible

Answer (score 3):

```
  while(TRUE)
    {
        if(Delay == 28)//Aprox to 1 tic
        {
            Delay = 0;//Reset delay to 0
            Tic ++;//Increase Tic by 1
        }
        else
        {
            Delay ++;//Increase Delay until it is at 28
        }
        Sleep(0.1);
    }
```

There's no way out of this loop.  Did you mean to put a `break` in  the `if` block?  Or maybe `while (Delay > 0)` (with it initially set to 1).

Also, as mentioned in the comments, if you say a function returns int, you need to make sure it has a return statement on every path.  Maybe instead of a `break`, you just want to `return Tic;`?